# ¿ Mi consulta me muetra resultados entre fechas por mes?

Tags: php, mysql

hola que tal en mi tabla tengo un columna de tipo varchar ejemplo

```
31-10-22
31-10-22
31-10-22
31-10-22
31-10-22
01-11-22
01-11-22
01-11-22
01-11-22
01-11-22
```

mi consulta es así

```
SELECT * FROM datos WHERE fecha BETWEEN '31-10-22' AND '01-11-22';
```

pero no me muestra nada, si hago la consulta en el mismo mes si me la muestra todos los resultados por ejemplo

```
SELECT * FROM datos WHERE fecha BETWEEN '01-10-22' AND '31-10-22';
```

que podría ser soy novato en esto. saludos

Comment: Simplemente debes cambiar el tipo de dato de tu tabla en tu Base de Datos, los campos de tipo fecha se definen como "date" nunca String o Varchar. Actualiza eso y prueba nuevamente :)

Comment: Si la columna es VARCHAR y quieres tratarla como fecha, mejor usa tipo DATE.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con algo así convirtiendo en tipo "date" al columna y buscando con formatos de fecha.

```
SELECT str_to_date(fecha, '%d-%m-%y') FROM datos  WHERE str_to_date(fecha, '%d-%m-%y') BETWEEN '2022-09-01' AND '2022-10-31';
```

Expico un poco lo que hice, cuando buscas por strings no puedes buscar por rangos, porque el motor de base de datos no entiende que es una fecha (o un numero)

entonces, lo que hay que hacer es cambiarle el tipo de dato.
con el str_to_date, le mandas el string y el formato de fecha que contiene (en nuestro caso día, mes, año) y ya siendo fecha, se pueden buscar por rangos con el between.

Comment: Por favor mira [answer] para mejorar tu respuesta.

Comment: que tal ya lo intente pero me muestra los datos vacíos

Comment: hice unos cambios a la respuesta, puedes revisar?

Comment: muchas gracias mi buen MrDonPh0x si funciono eres un crack